# An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string

in `AppBundle:Dashboard:index.html.twig` at line 46.

This is happening because of `appointment.employees`. Can someone explain it?
This is the entity with the relation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="LamecoEmployee")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="appointment_lamecoemployee",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="appointment_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="lamecoempoloyee_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $employees;
```

This is the view:

```
{% for appointment in appointments %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{appointment.startDate|date('H:i')}}</td>
        <td>{{appointment.client.companyname}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{appointment.employees}}</td>
        <td>{{appointment.description}}</td>
    </tr> <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to iterate through appointment.employees as it's a collection (the same as appointments), that or convert it to something twig can render inline.

E.g.

```
{% for employee in appointment.employees %}
    {{employee.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Or, if you just wanted a count and no iteration:

```
{{appointment.employees|length}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're trying to print a collection of employees. PHP simply doesn't know how to do that.

The annotation `@ORM\ManyToMany` on your attribute `$employees` indicate that an Appointment can be linked to several LamecoEmployee (and an employee can be linked to several appointments). So the type of the attribute $employee is not a LamecoEmployee, it is a collection of LamecoEmployee.

You can print ONE employee if you defined the `__toString()` method in your LamecoEmployee class, but you can't print a collection of employees at once. To print all employees of your appointment, you can loop on `appointment.employees`:

```
{% for employee in appointment.employees %}
    {{ employee }}
{% endfor %}
```